# How to pivot hierchical data into seprate columns

Tags: sql-server, presto

I have a requirement where data looks like below table , where PL-79 do not have parent record.
I provided the sample data which consists 4-levels but in actual case number of levels are greater than 4 .

My Parent-Child table:

**Input**

| Parent | Child |
| --- | --- |
| PL-79 | 08 |
| PL-79 | 30 |
| 30 | 20 |
| 30 | 25 |
| 30 | 21 |
| 21 | 09-A |
| 21 | 09-b |

I want to pivot the Parent-Child table into this table:
**Output Needed**

| lvl1 | lvl2 | lvl3 | lvl4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PL-79 | 08 |  |  |
| PL-79 | 30 | 20 |  |
| PL-79 | 30 | 25 |  |
| PL-79 | 30 | 21 | 09-A |
| PL-79 | 30 | 21 | 09-b |

Also it would be great if someone provide us the solution in prestoDB as presto do not work with recursive cte. If not simple SQL-server solution is alright .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a finite maximum number of levels :

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ParentCode VARCHAR(5), ChildCode VARCHAR(5));
INSERT INTO @Table (ParentCode, ChildCode) VALUES
('PL-79',  '08'), ('PL-79',  '30'), ('30',  '20'),
('30',  '25'), ('30',  '21'), ('21',  '09-A'),
('21', '09-b');

SELECT l1.ParentCode AS lvl1,  l1.ChildCode AS lvl2,  l2.ChildCode AS lvl3,  l3.ChildCode AS lvl4
  FROM @Table l1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Table l2
      ON l1.ChildCode = l2.ParentCode
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Table l3
      ON l2.ChildCode = l3.ParentCode
WHERE l1.ParentCode NOT IN (SELECT ChildCode FROM @Table);
```

| lvl1 | lvl2 | lvl3 | lvl4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PL-79 | 08 |  |  |
| PL-79 | 30 | 20 |  |
| PL-79 | 30 | 25 |  |
| PL-79 | 30 | 21 | 09-A |
| PL-79 | 30 | 21 | 09-b |